# Unregister action in QgsShortcutManager

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-3

I would like to unregister an action and assign it to an other sequence, but doesn't work.
In `initGuit` method from my Qgis plugin i do :

```
act = QgsGui.shortcutsManager().objectForSequence(QKeySequence('Ctrl+M'))
QgsGui.shortcutsManager().unregisterAction(act)

sht= QShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+M"), self.iface.mainWindow()) # If i change to Ctrl+J eg. it works
sht.activated.connect(lambda : print('test'))
```